# Select column by different column function in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following table in Access 2010.

```
EQID Breaker Circuit Rating
1    A       One     1000
2    A       Two     1500
3    A       Three   500
4    A       Four    1000
5    B       One     1500
6    B       Two     2000
```

I want to create a query to Group by Breaker, and show the Minimum Rating and the associated Circuit for that rating.  I understand how to do this without showing the Circuit for the Minimum rating.

My desired query result would be:

```
EQID Breaker Circuit Rating
1    A       Three   500
2    B       One     1500
```

Comment: Show the query you have tried and we'll work it out together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Breaker, MIN(Rating) AS min_rating
    FROM table
    GROUP BY Breaker
) AS b
ON a.Breaker = b.Breaker AND
   a.Rating = b.min_rating;
```

SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea4fb/2

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Chad.  I didn't realize it was answered so quickly, didn't get the automated notification of response.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below:

```
SELECT t.EQID, t.Breaker, t.Circuit, t.Rating 
FROM test t 
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT a.Breaker, MIN(a.Rating) AS Rating 
  FROM test a 
  GROUP BY Breaker
 ) AS tmp 
ON tmp.Breaker = t.Breaker AND tmp.Rating = t.Rating;
```

Sql fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe796/19

Comment: Access may complain about a "circular reference" here: `MIN(a.Rating) AS Rating`  If that happens, you can eliminate the error by not re-using the field name as the alias: `MIN(a.Rating) AS MinOfRating`

Comment: Great catch HansUp. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Anda and @Hansup for the info.  It helped immensely.